# How to add namespace in aspx file?

Tags: asp.net

i have added C# code in `aspx` file, but it is showing error

> The type or namespace name 'Mail' does not exist in the class or
>   namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

How i can add nampespace to aspx file i have tried `<%@ import namespace="Westwind.Tools"%>` but it does not work?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>
```

Comment: Isn't this action against MVC ideology? All data should be inside the model, and only model should be responsible for acquiring of custom data.

Comment: @Johnny_D yeah... like creating MVC app with web forms goes nicely and smoothly...

Comment: It always seems odd to have to use Import (VB) in a page we've already said is using C#

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming that it's in a website and that the page doesn't have code behind?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();


        }

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This seems to work for me.

If it's not in a website and/or it has code behind why do you need to reference the namespace in the aspx file?

Hope this helps

Comment: but why it is not working for me? still the same error see link
http://worldwidefreightservices.com/sb/sheery/new.aspx

Comment: i have put the same code which you have given, but still the same error see link http://worldwidefreightservices.com/sb/sheery/me.aspx

Comment: The error displays that it is using "Microsoft .NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2443; ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2407" but System.Net.Mail only came into .net in version 2 ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx

Comment: It means that your website configuration in IIS has not be set to using .net 2. This will need to be set through IIS Manager if you have remote desktop access to the server. Otherwise it will require an update through your hosting management console, or a support ticket to your host.

Answer (score 4):

To add the namespace globally instead of page-by-page, just put the namespace in your web.config.

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Your.Namespace"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You might have to restart Visual Studio for the IntelliSense to kick in.

You can also create a mini web.config in a directory to only import the namespace into ASPX files within that directory and sub-directories instead of applying it globally.

Answer (score 1):

You can import and create an optional alias for the namespace:

`<%@ Import Namespace="SP=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" %>`

and then use the alias like:

`<%= var spContext = new SP.ClientContext("someSharePointUrl"); %>`

Comment: It is  nearly a 13 years old question and it has an accepted answer!