# How can I add namespaces to my asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've just added Ajax Control Toolkit with NuGet, and I want to add the following piechart:

```
       <ajaxToolkit:PieChart ID="pieChart1" runat="server" ChartHeight="300" 
            ChartWidth="450" ChartTitle="Widget Production in the world" 
            ChartTitleColor="#0E426C"> 
            <PieChartValues>
                <ajaxToolkit:PieChartValue Category="United States" Data="45" 
                PieChartValueColor="#6C1E83" PieChartValueStrokeColor="black" />
                <ajaxToolkit:PieChartValue Category="Europe" Data="25" 
                PieChartValueColor="#D08AD9" PieChartValueStrokeColor="black" />
                <ajaxToolkit:PieChartValue Category="Asia" Data="17" 
                PieChartValueColor="#6586A7" PieChartValueStrokeColor="black" />
                <ajaxToolkit:PieChartValue Category="Australia" Data="13" 
                PieChartValueColor="#0E426C" PieChartValueStrokeColor="black" />
            </PieChartValues>
        </ajaxToolkit:PieChart>
```

However, my page has no clue what PieChart is, how can I add ajaxToolkit and link it to the dll file in the aspx page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add namespace in aspx file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369658/how-to-add-namespace-in-aspx-file)

Comment: @Castrohenge Im aware of <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail"%>, but where do I define ajaxToolkit?

Answer (score 1):

Mine looks like this:

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
```

If you drop an ajax control onto the form, it should create the registration for you. Mine above is an auto generated reference to the ajax toolkit. You also have to add a reference to the Ajax dll through the project references (although Nuget might have done this already, not sure).

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following images will be useful. And download the needed AJAX .dll file.

Add this:

`<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>`

Step 1:

[image: Step 1]

Step 2:

[image: Step 2]

Step 3:

[image: Step 3]

Step 4:

[image: Step 4]