# How can I include a class library into a (non MVC) ASP.net Razor website so that I don't have to use the using statement?

Tags: c#, razor

I have a C# ASP.Net Razor (non MVC) webpage...

```
@using QuickCodeLearning.Customers.Utilities;
@{
    var cus = CustomerUtilities.GetCustomerInformation(1);
}
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         Display a Customer
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <p>@cus.fname @cus.lname @cus.FavFruit</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

I'm including a class library (QuickCodeLearning.Customers.Utilities) via a using statement.

Everything works fine.

[image]

My question is can I add this class library to my Web.Config file so that I don't have to have the using statement at the top of each page?

Here is my `Web.Config` file...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CustomersEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CustomersEF.csdl|res://*/CustomersEF.ssdl|res://*/CustomersEF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LT5V6V8W1\SQLSERVERROCKS;initial catalog=sandbox;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode ="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I tried adding <page> <namespace> to the Web.Config file like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="QuickCodeLearning.Customers.Utilities" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CustomersEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CustomersEF.csdl|res://*/CustomersEF.ssdl|res://*/CustomersEF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LT5V6V8W1\SQLSERVERROCKS;initial catalog=sandbox;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode ="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But this does not work. When I remove the using statement the page stops working.

What am I missing?

Update:

The answer (which I'm sure is correct) is not working for me. My project does not have a Views folder. When I add a new folder to my web project and included the App.Config settings it does not solve my issue. I closed and repopened Visual Studio. I restarted IIS.

I noticed that a views folder is created when you have Visual Studio 2012 create a MVC project, however I'm not working with a MVC site here. I have a basic website that is using the Razor engine.

Comment: Here is how you can reproduce this issue. First create a Class Library with a trivial function like "Add". Compile to a dll. Then Create a basic one page website with an index.cshtml file. Then open you website's folder with Visual Studio 2012. Create a Solution file with Visual Studio. Then Add a reference to the class library dll. Now you can only use the dll by putting a @using statement at the to of index.cshtml. My question is how can I add this to a config file so I don' t have to include the using statement on every page. This is not a MVC project.

Comment: can you test my answer

Comment: There's an answer to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2369664/2386514

Answer (score 5):

In the `Web.Config` file in `Views` folder **(not the main `Web.Config` in project's root)**, find this section:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      ...
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Here you can add your additional Namespace and it will be on all Views.

Comment: Two things... This is not a MVC site. And my project does not have a Views folder.

Comment: @codingguy3000 ok and where is your View located? The thing is Web.Config is not MVC thing. It just file that holds config for folder where it's located (and subfolders)

Comment: @codingguy3000 will you answer - have you tried to add your namespases in `<system.web.webPages.razor>` -> `<pages>` -> `<namespaces>`?

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config, do like this:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.WebPages.WebPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Configuration" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="QuickCodeLearning.Customers.Utilities" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some interesting things (Add namespaces with Razor) in this link http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/add-namespaces-with-razor

The Idea is to add namespace to all pages :

we create a new class called PreApplicationStart , like this :

```
using Microsoft.WebPages.Compilation;
public class PreApplicationStart
{
   public static void InitializeApplication()
   {
       CodeGeneratorSettings.AddGlobalImport("QuickCodeLearning.Customers.Utilities");
   }
}
```

Add the following code in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PreApplicationStart), "InitializeApplication")]
```

When we start our website, InitializeApplication will be executed before Application_Start in global.asax

Hope  it helps

Comment: I'm not running a MVC web application. I have a web site that is using the Razor view engine (.cshtml pages).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put them in the correct `<system.web>` section of web.config. e.g.

```
   <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <pages>
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Data" />
            <add namespace="System.Text"/>
          </namespaces>
        </pages>  
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

The purpose of the namespace section is to get around having to do the import in the .aspx and other active server page. Code behind in C# still requires you to have the using statements at the top of your .cs file.