# gridview in web forms Could not load type

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a ASP.NET, WebForms web application and I'm using Entity framework.
I need to put some data from DB to GridView, but when I add the most basic code to my List.aspx page for GridView, I get error saying "Could not Load Type 'Report'" Error:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReports" runat="server" ItemType="Report" SelectMethod="gvReports_GetData"></asp:GridView>
```

Packages that I'm using:

```
package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
```

The model for Entity looks like this:
[image]

And the SelectMethod looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<Report> gvReports_GetData()
    {
        FinReports_ConceptEntities db = new FinReports_ConceptEntities();
        return db.Reports;
    }
```

**EDIT** I followed this tutorial
https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/retrieving-data

Comment: Can you show Report model class?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how that is relevant. Class Report is automaticaly generated from Entity via database first model, and is not edited, and the GridView should automaticaly generate columns for that class since AutomaticalyGenerateColumns is true. In short, everything is auto-generated, and I could't have made a mistake in codebehind of those auto-generated components.

Comment: Add AutoGenerateColumns="True"  property to your gridview. Also You add namespaces in ItemType="ProjectName.FolderName.Report"

Comment: I got the same mistake. I do beleave that those variables have some defaults and if they are not mentioned, they'll have that default value, so no need to say AutoGenerateColumns="True" if AutoGenerateColumns's default value is already true.

Comment: @mww It is misleading to say to use `ProjectName.FolderName.Report`. You should use the namespace, which does not always line up with `ProjectName.FolderName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you haven't got the namespace referenced correctly on your page.

There are three solutions:

---

Use a fully qualified name for your item type.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReports" runat="server" ItemType="MyNamespace.Report" SelectMethod="gvReports_GetData"></asp:GridView>
```

---

Import the namespace at the top of your page with an import namespace directive (similar to a `using` statement in a C# class). See [How to add namespace in aspx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369658/how-to-add-namespace-in-aspx-file)

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```

---

Or you can import the namespace for all ASPX pages in your project by adding some configuration to `web.config` file. See [How to add namespaces in web.config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586499/how-to-add-namespaces-in-web-config-file)

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MyNamespace" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>  
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

---

Note that it is not `MyProject.MyClass` syntax when fully qualifying it. It is `MyNamespace.MyClass`. It just so happens your project and namespace are the same, but this won't always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that in ItemType property, insead of name of my class (Report), I should have put the full path to that class (your_project_name.your_class_name). That was not mentioned in the tutorial listed above.